# How to test input form that sends chat on Enter with React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have the following Chat box that sends the chat when someone clicks on Enter. This is working as expected in normal life but RTL is disagreeing.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Test() {
  const [chatText, setChatText] = useState("");

  function sendChat() {
    setChatText("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        rows={2}
        value={chatText}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setChatText(e.target.value);
        }}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            sendChat();
          }
        }}
        aria-label="chat-input"
      />
      <button onClick={sendChat}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is working fine. You send a text and the chat box clears when you press `Enter`.

The following is the test I have written in RTL, but it is not working.

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, waitFor, act } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import user from "@testing-library/user-event";

import Test from "./index";

describe("Chat", () => {
  test("clear text on Enter", async () => {
    render(<Test />);
    let textBox = screen.getByLabelText("chat-input");
    await act(async () => {
      textBox.focus();
      expect(textBox).toHaveFocus();
      await user.keyboard("hello");
      await user.keyboard("{Enter}");
      await user.keyboard("hello");
      await waitFor(() => {
        expect(textBox).toHaveValue("hello");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Is the test I've written wrong or is something wrong with the code?
RTL is not triggering the clear on Enter part, instead is showing `hellohello`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-dewdney-x3x5hd This is the codesandbox but it is throwing a different error in the sandbox. If you run on create-react-app, it shows 
`Expected the element to have value: hello Received: hellohello`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `act` wrapper

```
describe('Chat', () => {
  test('clear text on Enter', async () => {
    render(<Test />);
    let textBox = screen.getByLabelText('chat-input');

    textBox.focus();
    expect(textBox).toHaveFocus();
    await user.keyboard('hello');
    await user.keyboard('{Enter}');
    await user.keyboard('hello');
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(textBox).toHaveValue('hello');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: removing the `act` is throwing the `act` error. `Warning: An update to Test inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Done some digging around and it may have to do something with user.keyboard in general. This might work better instead for you:

```
// import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"

await userEvent.type(textBox, 'hello{enter}')
// little safety check that the input reset after enter key
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(textBox).toHaveValue('');
});

await userEvent.type(textBox, 'hello')
// check for new hello value
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(textBox).toHaveValue('hello');
});
```

Sidenote, I highly recommend explicitly defining your onChange and onKeyDown functions rather than making them anonymous arrow functions. ie:

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  setChatText(e.target.value)
}
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  e.preventDefault()

  if (e.key === 'Enter') sendChat()
}
```

The reason is that as your app scales, anonymous arrow functions are less performant than declarative ones because they have to be re-initialized every render. This alone has its use cases, but generally because your input is controlled it's being re-rendered every onChange which means it's reinitializing those anonymous arrow functions over and over again.

Comment: This also didn't work for me. :/

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to make your tests pass with user-event, however using `fireEvent` works fine

```
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

import Test from "./App";

describe("Chat", () => {
  test("clear text on Enter", () => {
    render(<Test />);
    const textBox = screen.getByTestId("custom-element");
    fireEvent.change(textBox, {
      target: { value: "hello" }
    });
    expect(textBox).toHaveValue("hello");
    fireEvent.keyDown(textBox, {
      key: "Enter",
      code: "Enter",
      charCode: 13
    });
    expect(textBox).toHaveValue("");
    fireEvent.change(textBox, {
      target: { value: "hola" }
    });
    expect(textBox).toHaveValue("hola");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to apply few things:

- set `user-event` not use it directly
- As @vladislav said, remove `act` wrapper. Testing Library already wraps events using `act` inside. If you still face `act` related error, better to check [React Testing Library FAQ](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/faq/)
- use `findByLabelText` or `findByTestId` to get element.
- I recommend you to check every result of each event.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, waitFor, act } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import Test from "./App";

describe("Chat", () => {
  test("clear text on Enter", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup()

    render(<Test />);

    let textBox = await screen.findByLabelText("chat-input");

    textBox.focus();
    expect(textBox).toHaveFocus();

    await user.keyboard("hello");
    expect(textBox).toHaveValue("hello");

    await user.keyboard("{enter}");
    expect(textBox).toHaveValue("");

    await user.keyboard("hello");
    expect(textBox).toHaveValue("hello");
  });
});
```

Comment: Removing `act` is throwing this error `Warning: An update to Test inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).` and the test to not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with this test refactor, which uses `userEvent.type` instead of `user.keyboard` and wraps each typing event in `act`:

```
describe("Chat", () => {
  test("clear text on Enter", async () => {
    render(<Test />);
    const textBox = screen.getByLabelText("chat-input");

    act(() => userEvent.type(textBox, "hello"));
    act(() => userEvent.type(textBox, "{Enter}"));
    act(() => userEvent.type(textBox, "hello"));

    expect(textBox).toHaveValue("hello");
  });
});
```